# What is the difference between "а то" and "а не то"?

Tags: conjunctions

What is the difference between "а то" and "а не то"?

Answer (score 6):

**А то and а не то** (conjunctions) are used as **synonyms** when they connect two sentences and the action in the second sentence  could happen but for the real action or event from the first one.( meaning **otherwise**, or else -иначе, в противном случае). Such contexts often refer to threat.

> Отдай машинку, а то <а не то> маме пожалуюсь.
> Придется дать кролику капусты, а то <а не то> он убежит.

Another usage where these conjunctions are synonymous is connecting phrases or sentences with obvious change of actions ( meaning "or"-или)

> Купались, ходили за грибами, а то <а не то> (или) брали лодку и уплывали на соседний остров
>
> Иногда засыпала сразу и спала всю ночь, а то <а не то> до рассвета читала романы. = Иногда засыпала сразу и спала всю ночь или (же)  до рассвета читала романы.

Even when  these conjunctions are synonymous, there's still a slight difference in the function of the word **то**, which refers to the previous context in **а не то** and to the context which follows in **а то**.

These conjunctions are not interchanged expressing  other meanings.

1.**А то** can express the **reason**( meaning **because**)

> Пойду, а то уже поздно [‘пойду, потому что уже поздно’].

2.**А то** showing a change of the former situation
The situations are in opposition.

> Теперь ей лучше (now), а то все болела (earlier).
> Несколько ночей прошло, пока научились(then) находить свой овраг, а то плутали.(earlier).

3. **А то!** colloquial interjection meaning *Sure, of course, yes*

> Пойдешь на каток? – А то!

I didn't consider these combinations with "что, чтобы". It's another big question.

Answer (score 5):

**А не то** is somewhat antiquated, and doesn't have **а то**'s range of other possible meanings besides "or else".